# How to parse this XML(XBRL) using Php

Tags: php, xml, domparser, xbrl

I am new to PHP and I need to parse an XML file, make some changes in it and write it.

The file looks like this:

```
<xbrli:xbrl xsi:schemaLocation="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi http://www.xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi-2006.xsd"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:odrpt.0001.list.req.02.00="http://sbr.gov.au/rprt/ato/odrpt/odrpt.0001.list.request.02.00.report"
                    xmlns:ref="http://www.xbrl.org/2006/ref"
                    xmlns:dtyp.02.24="http://sbr.gov.au/fdtn/sbr.02.24.dtyp"
                    xmlns:pyid.02.10="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyid/pyid.02.10.data"
                    xmlns:emsup.02.08="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/em/emsup/emsup.02.08.data"
                    xmlns:emsup.02.20="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/em/emsup/emsup.02.20.data"
                    xmlns:xbrldt="http://xbrl.org/2005/xbrldt"
                    xmlns:SqNumDim.02.01_typedelement="http://sbr.gov.au/dims/SqNumDim.02.01.dims"
                    xmlns:pyde.02.20="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyde/pyde.02.20.data"
                    xmlns:dtyp.02.00="http://sbr.gov.au/fdtn/sbr.02.00.dtyp"
                    xmlns:pyid.02.00="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyid/pyid.02.00.data"
                    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
                    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                    xmlns:odrpt.0001.prv.02.00="http://sbr.gov.au/rprt/ato/odrpt/odrpt.0001.private.02.00.module"
                    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
                    xmlns:pyde.02.00="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyde/pyde.02.00.data"
                    xmlns:pyde.02.08="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyde/pyde.02.08.data"
                    xmlns:tech.01.02="http://sbr.gov.au/fdtn/sbr.01.02.tech"
                    xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi"
                    xmlns:RprtPyType.02.13="http://sbr.gov.au/dims/RprtPyType.02.13.dims"
                    xmlns:tech.01.03="http://sbr.gov.au/fdtn/sbr.01.03.tech"
                    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
                    xmlns:pyin.02.02="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyin/pyin.02.02.data"
                    xmlns:pyde.02.12="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyde/pyde.02.12.data"
                    xmlns:pyid.02.03="http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyid/pyid.02.03.data">
                    <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://sbr.gov.au/taxonomy/sbr_au_reports/ato/usmat/usmat_0001/usmat.0001.list.request.02.00.report.xsd"/>
                    <xbrli:context id="Context_Duration_ReportingParty">
                        <xbrli:entity>
                            <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.abr.gov.au/abn">111111111</xbrli:identifier>
                            <xbrli:segment>
                                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="RprtPyType.02.13:ReportPartyTypeDimension">RprtPyType.02.13:ReportingParty</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                            </xbrli:segment>
                        </xbrli:entity>
                        <xbrli:period>
                            <xbrli:startDate>2014-06-01</xbrli:startDate>
                            <xbrli:endDate>2014-06-01</xbrli:endDate>
                        </xbrli:period>
                    </xbrli:context>
                    <xbrli:context id="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">
                        <xbrli:entity>
                            <xbrli:identifier scheme="http://www.ato.gov.au/tfn">11111111</xbrli:identifier>
                            <xbrli:segment>
                                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="RprtPyType.02.13:ReportPartyTypeDimension">RprtPyType.02.13:SuperFundMember</xbrldi:explicitMember>
                            </xbrli:segment>
                        </xbrli:entity>
                        <xbrli:period>
                            <xbrli:startDate>2015-06-01</xbrli:startDate>
                            <xbrli:endDate>2014-06-01</xbrli:endDate>
                        </xbrli:period>
                    </xbrli:context>
                    <pyde.02.00:OrganisationNameDetails.OrganisationalName.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_ReportingParty">CCCorp</pyde.02.00:OrganisationNameDetails.OrganisationalName.Text>
                    <pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.FamilyName.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">CC</pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.FamilyName.Text>
                    <pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.GivenName.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">CC</pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.GivenName.Text>
                    <pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.OtherGivenName.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">CC</pyde.02.00:PersonNameDetails.OtherGivenName.Text>
                    <pyde.02.12:PersonDemographicDetails.Birth.DayofMonth contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">---18</pyde.02.12:PersonDemographicDetails.Birth.DayofMonth>
                    <pyde.02.12:PersonDemographicDetails.Birth.Month contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">--12</pyde.02.12:PersonDemographicDetails.Birth.Month>
                    <pyde.02.12:PersonDemographicDetails.Birth.Year contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">1960</pyde.02.12:PersonDemographicDetails.Birth.Year>
                    <pyid.02.10:Identifiers.SuperannuationMemberAccount.Identifier contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">true</pyid.02.10:Identifiers.SuperannuationMemberAccount.Identifier>
                    <pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Line1.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">CC</pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Line1.Text>
                    <pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Line2.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">CC</pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Line2.Text>
                    <pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.LocalityName.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">CC</pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.LocalityName.Text>
                    <pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Postcode.Text contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">3350</pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Postcode.Text>
                    <pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.StateOrTerritory.Code contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">CC</pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.StateOrTerritory.Code>
                    <pyde.02.08:AddressDetails.Country.Code contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">au</pyde.02.08:AddressDetails.Country.Code>
                    <emsup.02.08:SuperannuationFundDetails.UniqueSuperannuationIdentifier.Identifier contextRef="Context_Duration_SuperFundMember">abc1234ab</emsup.02.08:SuperannuationFundDetails.UniqueSuperannuationIdentifier.Identifier>
                </xbrli:xbrl>
```

**You can view it here: https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/cbfe5ebd**

I have tried DOM parser using some example, But i can't parse fields 
like :

```
<pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Postcode.Text>
```

Let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Following code:

```
       $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
            $xmldoc->load("myFile.xml");
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($xmldoc);
            $xpath->registerNamespace("xbrli",  "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance");
            $xpath->registerNamespace("pyde.02.00", "http://sbr.gov.au/icls/py/pyde/pyde.02.00.data");

            $organizationNameList = $xpath->query("/xbrli:xbrl/pyde.02.00:OrganisationNameDetails.OrganisationalName.Text[@contextRef='    Context_Duration_ReportingParty']");
            if($organizationNameList->length != 0){
                $orgNode = $organizationNameList->item(0);
                $orgName = $organizationNameList->length === 1 ? $organizationNameList->item(0)->nodeValue : null;
                echo $orgName;
            }
```

Using following code I am Able to read a value using specific query

Answer (score 1):

If you load the data using something like `simplexml_load_string` then the following will do the job...

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string( '
            <xbrli:xbrl xsi:schemaLocation="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi http://www.xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi-2006.xsd"
                       ... 
            </xbrli:xbrl>
');


foreach($xml->xpath('//pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Postcode.Text') as $postCode) {
    print_r($postCode);
}
```

You will need to add in the rest of the XML document, but this is just to show the main code as opposed to re-listing the whole xml.
The main thing is the XPath, which you can see has the namespace (pyde.02.00) as well as the elements name to locate the particular bit your after.  You should then be able to process these elements with your own code.

Edit:
To modify values, you need to change the corresponding part of the element.  So above prints out...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [contextRef] => Context_Duration_SuperFundMember
        )

    [0] => 3350
)
```

So if in the code you do

```
$postCode = $xml->xpath('//pyde.02.00:AddressDetails.Postcode.Text')[0];
$postCode[0] = "3351";
```

This results in the element now being

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [contextRef] => Context_Duration_SuperFundMember
        )

    [0] => 3351
)
```

If you want to save this to a file, then

```
$xml->asXml( $fileName );
```

Comment: Can you provide asolution that a parse all elements from xml file

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by 'parse all elements'?

Comment: By parsing I mean reading,  Now I am able to read all elements, Can you guide me how to change values. Please suggest me how can i change the values and generate update XML file

Comment: Loading from a file is just `simplexml_load_file($fileName);`